# Making acrodrdc your default pdf viewer

Tags: pdf

I have installed acrodrdc and everything works fine(I can launch it from the terminal and use it without any errors so far) but when I right click a pdf I can't see acrodrdc as one of the options.Is there a way to add it and also make it my default pdf viewer?

Comment: How did you install that?

Comment: From the ubuntu-software application.

Answer (score 2):

(in Ubuntu versions 18.04 and later) Right click on a pdf document and select `Properties`. Select the `Open With` tab and select the application you require from there and click `Set as default`.

This changes the default application not just for the selected file, but for all files with the same type.

You can also refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html.en) reference.

Comment: The problem is that even when I do that(I am using Ubuntu 16.04) acrordrdc doesn't appear although I installed the software from the ubuntu software application.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 20.04 (using the default Gnome desktop of 20.04)

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a solution to my problem.I first found the executable file of my application and then proceeded to make a file named "Acrordrdc.desktop" as in [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) guide but also added %F key to the end of the line of Exec.Then I simply copied that file in **/usr/share/applications/** and I was able to open .pdf files by open with/other applications